# Adding an object to NSMutableArray from UITextField

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uialertview

With this code, I get this error:

> '* -[NSMutableArray insertObject:atIndex:]: attempt to insert nil
>   object at 0'

```
categories=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init ];
UIAlertView* dialog = [[UIAlertView alloc] init];
    [dialog setDelegate:self];
    [dialog setTitle:@"Category name"];
    [dialog setMessage:@" "];
    [dialog addButtonWithTitle:@"Cancel"];
    [dialog addButtonWithTitle:@"OK"];

    nameField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20.0, 45.0, 245.0, 25.0)];
    [nameField setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [dialog addSubview:nameField];

    [dialog show];
    [dialog release];

    [categories addObject:[nameField text]];

    [nameField release];
    [categoryTable reloadData];
```

When I run this in simulator, I get a crash before the alert view even pops up. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An exception will be raised in an NSArray if you try to add a nil object. Check for the condition first:

```
if ([nameField text]) [categories addObject:[nameField text]];
```

EDIT:

Also from your code, you need to implement the UIAlertViewDelegate protocol and attempt to add your object to your array there.  For example:

```
- (void) showDialog {
    UIAlertView* dialog = [[UIAlertView alloc] init];
    [dialog setDelegate:self];
    [dialog setTitle:@"Category name"];
    [dialog setMessage:@" "];
    [dialog addButtonWithTitle:@"Cancel"];
    [dialog addButtonWithTitle:@"OK"];

    nameField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20.0, 45.0, 245.0, 25.0)];
    [nameField setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [dialog addSubview:nameField];

    [dialog show];
    [dialog release];
}


- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {

    if ([nameField text]) [categories addObject:[nameField text]];
    [categoryTable reloadData];

}
```

Assumes nameField and categories are iVars and you will need to release them when they are no longer needed.  You should also check which button was pressed in the delegate method.  HTH Dave

Comment: Hmm ok this seems to have solved the issue, however nothing is showing up in my table when I insert. Using this code: `if ([nameField text]) [categories insertObject:[nameField text] atIndex:[categories count]];`, nothing appears in my table. However if I use  `[categories insertObject:@"test" atIndex:[categories count]];`, then "test" does appear in my table. What can be causing this?

Comment: You need to create your UIAlertView and then show it and nothing else.  The rest of the code in your method will continue to run past the [dialog show] call (i.e., the nil object is being passed to the array).  Once you touch a button the appropriate delegate method will get called.  It is there you should try and do something with the result.